# Notation: Combine max and argmax

Tags: optimization, notation

I have some maximization where I am interested in the result and the parameters:

$$result=\max\{c^Tx:Ax\leq b\}$$
$$x=arg\max\{c^Tx:Ax\leq b\}$$

Is there a way to combine those? I formulate a pseudo algorithm, so I would like to omit text if possible. Otherwise, I could just refer to the "optimal solution" $x$.

Comment: Use argmax, then result $ = c^T x$.

Comment: The example invites to write it this way but it is simplified and my actual expression is much longer than $c^T x$

Comment: Then define an objective function $f$.